# Restore local master after making commits on it

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a project from `github`. When I started to develop a new requirement, I forgot to make a new branch and I modified the code on my local `master` instead in a new branch.

Now, I need to restore my local `master`, I mean, getting the same remote master code in my local master without any diff between them, and without sending nothing at all nor modifying code in github. How can I do that?

Comment: http://lrotherfield.com/blog/delete-remote-git-repo-to-specific-commit/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in 3 steps:

1. Create a new branch out of your existing `master` branch

   ```
   git checkout -b feature_branch
   ```
2. Delete your `master` branch

   ```
   git branch -D master
   ```
3. Create a fresh `master` branch

   ```
   git checkout -b master --track origin/master
   ```

This creates a feature branch (which you should have done in the start ideally), and a fresh master branch for you.

Comment: I did not understand the step 3. It creates a new branch master, but it does not fech the same things of feature_branch? And I will have the actual state of local master and feature_branch, right?

Comment: I already did it, but renaming the master as einverne said, instead delete it. All works very fine! Thank you a lot!

Comment: All your changes you've made so far live on feature branch. If you want to pull in changes of your master branch as well there, lookup more on `git rebase`.

Comment: Yeah! I did it. Thank you!